# Best way to check if several inputs have the same value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have some inputs (random number > 0) and each is inside a div with same class so I have this structure:

```
<div class="myclass"> <!-- div #1 -->
    <input name="name" class="input">
    <!-- other inputs that don't take care -->
</div>
...
<div class="myclass"> <!-- div #n -->
    <input name="name" class="input">
    <!-- other inputs that don't take care -->
</div>
```

I need to check that the value of every input doesn't match with other, so if I have in the first input `myname` as value in the input *n* I can't have `myname`.

I have the next JQuery code to iterate over all divs to extract the info about every div.

```
$('.myclass').each(function() {
    input = $(this).find('input[name="name"]').val();
});
```

And then, it sends all info (JSON parsed before) through jQuery ajax to PHP scripts which MUST revalidate that input values don't be equal.

So, the question is: what's the best way to go over all divs and know if value is repeated? I thought about making a $.each inside the each I have to iterate over all elements but I don't know about its performance.

And what about with PHP script, what's the best way to afford it?
Thank you.

**NOTE**: JSON parsed array, now have this structure:

```
{"user_info":{"app_id":0,"user_id":0},"contact":{"has_contact":0},"menu_items":[{"position":0,"name":"Nosotros","icon_id":"ic_delete_black_48dp.png","content":"nosotros"},{"position":1,"name":"Precios","icon_id":"ic_help_black_48dp.png","content":"nosotros"}]}
```

Don't worry about "user_info" and "has_contact" they are irrelevant, the *name* for which I was talking is the menu_items[index]['name'] value.

Comment: Not hard to test for unique...not totally clear however what goal is if they aren't unique. Do all uniques get submitted and discard duplicates? Or just test for no duplicates and only then submit?

Comment: The main idea is that when find the first duplicate throw an error and stop code. The problem is not the _how can I do it_, I know how, the question is about performance. Thank you.

Comment: Performance wise, loop once and store/check in hashmap would be fastest

Comment: Hashmap == js object or associative array, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.map()`, `.slice()`, `$.unique()`, `.length`

```js
// return `input` values
var inputs = $.map($(".myclass input"), function(el) {return el.value});
// check if `unique` array `.length` is equal to `unique` array `.length`
var unique = $.unique(inputs.slice(0)).length === inputs.length;

console.log(inputs, unique);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass"> <!-- div #1 -->
    <input name="name" class="input" value="abc">
    <!-- other inputs that don't take care -->
</div>
...
<div class="myclass"> <!-- div #n -->
    <input name="name" class="input" value="abc">
    <!-- other inputs that don't take care -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, the only thing I don't understand is why you slice the array on the $.unique() function. I know that $.unique removes duplicated elements so if returned array length != original array length there was a duplicated but why slice(0) the array? Thank you :D

Comment: @legomolina _"but why slice(0) the array?"_ `$.unique()` would change the original `inputs` array. Try `var arr = [1,1,2]; $.unique(arr); console.log(arr);`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it *(code example not shown ...)* is to create a hash in which each received value *(**i-f** it is a string or can be **unambiguously** coerced into one ...)* is the key, and a don't-care value is the value.

Start with an empty hash.  For each input, test if a key matching that input already exists in the hash. If so, you've got a dupe. If not, add the input as a new key. *(The associated value doesn't matter ...)*  After all inputs are checked, the hash can be discarded.

(This strategy works for any programming language that supports hashes ... which, these days, is "all of them."  It is also, in principle, an efficient way to count how many times any particular element occurs.)

*Caution:* Do not use this technique where the input value is of a different data-type than that of the underlying collection-type, which in JavaScript is (only) "a string," and there is any possibility at all that two inputs which you deem to be "different" could be coerced into the same (string) key value.  The algorithm will not be able to tell them apart.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do this with PHP I would use array_unique() function....